Movie where a tomboy has to change and be girly
I saw this movie when I was younger (early 2000's) and I unfortunately can't remember the exact plot but there's a girl and she is very tomboyish and has this friend who is a guy and for some reason I think a family member maybe a gran or aunt who is very classy and girly, and forces her to change from being a tomboy into a girly classy person.

I can remember there's a scene where she is standing beside the
family member at some fancy event outside and she's standing there
dressed very classy and posh and the dog of another lady recognises
her, because when she was a tomboy she would play with the dog, and
jumps out of its owner's arms and runs over to her and starts to bark
at her so she'll play with him.
I can't remember that much more but I know that the guy she was
friends with ends up being her love interest and is really annoyed
that she isn't acting like herself and they have an argument over it.
I also thought the main character was Lindsay Lohan but I looked up
her movies and from what I saw I don't think it was her.


Can you give a time frame to "...when I was younger" ... would this be early 90's or perhaps older, for example?

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

TurboPT It was around 2005-2010, thank you so much for that detailed answer but I looked further into this movie and unfortunately it wasn't the same movie but I still love the sound of it!!

Any other unique detailes about the movie? There are a lot of movies with a similar theme, She's the man, All a girl wants, The princess diaries....

Sounds like "What a Girl Wants" with Amanda Bynes
She ends up changing the way she is for her dad, in order for him to do well with his political campaign, much to the dismay of her boyfriend.  Before Daphne changes, she played with I believe it was the Queen's dog, which she sees again when she's changed and ignores. You can see a low-quality clip of it here.

"Daphne, a free-spirited American 17-year-old raised by her equally free-spirited mother goes to England to establish a relationship with her father, who turns out to be a prominent political figure heavily involved in social customs. Daphne must attempt to fit in with the social requirements demanded of her, while also getting to know her father, dealing with his territorial other daughter, and maintaining her own self-identity."





I don't remember anything about a dog or "posh" looks, but could it be Ladybugs?


Ladybugs is a 1992 American sports-comedy film starring Rodney
  Dangerfield and directed by Sidney J. Furie. Dangerfield plays a
  Denver businessman who takes over a girls soccer team that the company
  he works for sponsors. The film also stars Jackée Harry as his
  assistant coach, Ilene Graff as his girlfriend, Jonathan Brandis as
  his girlfriend's son, and Vinessa Shaw as his boss's daughter.
In his personal life, Chester is engaged to Bess (Ilene Graff), who has
  a son, Matthew (Jonathan Brandis), from a previous marriage. Matthew
  just happens to be a great athlete, but poor grades get him kicked off
  the soccer team. Chester invites Matthew to watch the Ladybugs
  practice and to get some tips. Matthew has a crush on Kimberly from
  school and it is partly due to this that Chester persuades him to
  dress like a girl and play for the team under the name Martha. With
  only Chester, Matthew and Julie knowing the secret of Martha's
  identity, the team wins the rest of its games to get to the
  championship game. Kimberly makes friends with Martha, not knowing
  "she" is in fact Matthew.
Just before the championship game, Bess finds out that Matthew has
  been dressing as a girl to play. She becomes angry with Chester,
  making him drop Matthew from the team. Kimberly, who has not been
  playing well, is also dropped on the request of Chester's boss.
The Ladybugs go down 3-0 in the first half. At halftime, Matthew
  reveals to Kimberly and the rest of the team that he is Martha. His
  honesty fires the team up and with Chester's encouragement, Kimberly
  scores the winning goal on a penalty kick. As the Ladybugs win the
  championship, Chester gets his promotion. Bess and Chester get married
  while Matthew and Kimberly begin
  dating. - 
  Ladybugs(film).


